# Query a Custom Post Type using SELECT that has ACF fields to compare dates

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, custom-field, select

So I have a CPT called ads that has ACF fields of ad_start_date and ad_end_date. I am trying to write a custom WP query using a SELECT statement instead of using WP_Query because I am return an ajax request so I need to choose exactly the fields to send over.

So for a test I did use the WP_Query method and it works perfectly. But in order to get acf fields, or say Featured Image this WP Query method will need to be on a template php file. I need a custom SELECT statement so I can choose exactly what fields I need to send over to the JavaScript side in one json response.
FYI, this function retrieves an array of ids from a previous AJAX request response thus you see the 'post_in' argument. But again the below function works perfectly, but cannot use it since a response from WP_Query is limited and needs the WP Loop or the post ID to pass in to the ACF

```
get_field('ad_start_date', post->ID)
```

function. I need this query to get everything on this one query call to send back as json response.

```
function get_ads() {
    $id = $_POST['ids'];
    $integerIDs = json_decode( $id, true);
    $todays_date = date('Ymd', strtotime("now"));
    $newargs = array(
        'numberposts'   => -1,
        'post_type'     => 'ads',
        'post__in'      => $integerIDs,
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
        'meta_query'    => array(
            array(
                'key'       => 'ad_start_date',
                'compare'   => '<',
                'type'      => 'numeric',
                'value'     => $todays_date,
                ),
            array(
                'key'       => 'ad_end_date',
                'value'     => $todays_date,
                'compare'   => '>',
                'type'      => 'numeric',
            ),
        ), 
    );
    $the_final_query = new WP_Query( $newargs );
    echo json_encode($the_final_query);
    wp_die();
}
```

So here are my attempts at using the Custom mysql statement in mysql workbench to get this data. But I am not having any success. Does anyone understand where my issue is?

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.ID
AND( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'ad_start_date' AND wp_postmeta.meta_value < 
20190620)  
AND ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'ad_end_date' AND wp_postmeta.meta_value > 
20190620)
WHERE wp_posts.post_type = 'ads'
AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
```

Second attempt trying to cast to number since meta_value is longtext data type

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.ID
AND( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'ad_start_date' AND (CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value 
AS 
UNSIGNED) < 20190620) ) 
AND ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'ad_end_date' AND (CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value 
AS 
UNSIGNED) > 20190620) )
WHERE wp_posts.post_type = 'ads'
AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can output the exact SQL query generated by WP_Query using

```
$the_final_query->request
```

This should give you the starting point you need to customize your SQL